# Kubuntu 20.04 dolphin window arrangement

Tags: kubuntu, window, dolphin

Is there any setting for the *Dolphin* window to stay in the position i choose ?
I mean that when i position the window after closing it , it stays in the place i choose when i reopen it.By default the *Dolphin* window always opens in the left corner of the display.
KDE Plasma version 5.18.5   /   Kubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Does it happen for any other software (e.g. Konsole, GwenView)?

Comment: Same thing with Konsole, etc.

Comment: Only some applications like Chrome , VLC (Snap install) , Opera keep the position that i choose.

Comment: Have you already tried using "Window Rules"? Look under system settings *Workspace > Window Management > Window Rules*

Comment: @Nmath i have a blank space in ''Window Rules'' no options for settings.

Comment: ... because you have to make them.  look in the Top Right corner: `New...` - put "dolphin" as exact match in "Window Class" and there are three more tabs of options on how you would like the application to behave.  If this works for you please let me know I can post as answer.

Comment: @Nmath it works , you can post as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having to install anything, Kubuntu has a **"Window Rules"** feature in System Settings that gives you fine-tuned control of window management, including per-application rules.

The settings are located under **System Settings > Workspace > Window Management > Window Rules**

[image: Window Rules]

To set custom rules for Dolphin, create a new rule by clicking **"New..."** in the top right of the Window Rules window.

Set the criteria for your new rule in the first tab, **"Window Matching"**:  You want the rule to affect Dolphin, so would enter the package name `dolphin` as an "Exact Match".  This will make sure that the rule takes effect when using Dolphin.

[image: Window Matching]

The next three tabs allow you to choose what happens to windows that meet the criteria in the first tab: *"Size & Position", "Arrangement & Access", and "Appearance & Fixes"*

In your case, you would use the **"Size & Position"** tab.  As an example, I have set the window to open 200 pixels from the left and 200 pixels from the top with a window size of 1000x800 pixels.

[image: Size & Position]

You can adjust these options however you like.

Comment: Is it possible to set a custom rule (say, open at the center of the screen) for all GUI apps?

Comment: I can't answer that for "all apps".  It's way too broad of a generalization especially since some apps have their own way to launch in specific positions and sizes.  The best thing I can say is to play around with it. You're not going to break anything that you can't immediately reverse.